# Sending data to a url -

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

This is my html template

```
        {% for i in searched_inf %}
            <div>
                <p>Result: <a href="{{ i.ig_link }}" target="_blank">IG link
                    for {{ i.user.first_name }} {{ i.user.last_name }}</a>
                    <button>
                        <a href="{% url 'messages' %}">Send a message</a>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

As you can see when the button is pressed, user is redirected to the messages url. I have a separate messages view to handle this url. I want to send data from this template. When the button is clicked, I want to send the i.user.first_name value, so that I can access it in the messages view.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem? If so please consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a view like this.

`urls.py`

```
path('message/<str:first_name>', my_view, name='messages')
```

`views.py`

```
def my_view(request, fist_name):
    ... process  stuff here ...
```

`html template`

```
<button>
    <a href="{% url 'messages'  i.user.first_name %}">Send a message</a>
</button>
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/) for django docs.